# h:commandButton not redirecting to other jsf page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, commandbutton

Hello I have two XHTML pages:
1-login.jsf 2-menu.jsf 
i m trying to go from page1  to page2  by clicking on a button but it doesnt work.Here is my code:
login.jsf

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/styles.css"/>
</head>

<h:body>
<h:form id="LoginForm">
<h:panelGrid  style= "width: 467px; height: 88px">

<h:outputLabel value="Login"/>
<h:inputText value="#{loginBean.login}" id="loginID" />
<h:message for="loginID" tooltip="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" style="COLOR: #ff0000;"/>

<h:outputLabel value="Mot de Passe"/>
<h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}" id="pwdID" />
<h:message for="pwdID" tooltip="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" style="COLOR:    #ff0000;"/>
<h:message />
</h:panelGrid>

<h:commandButton id="validerID" value="Valider" action="#{loginBean.authentification}"       type="submit"/>
<h:commandButton  id="resetID" value="Reset" type="reset"/>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And here is the code of the ManagedBean:

package com.fst.bibliotheque.beans;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
   import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

public class LoginBean {

```
private String login;
private String password;


public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}
public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String authentification(){

    FacesContext fc=FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if("admin".equals(this.login) && "admin".equals(password)){
        return "success";
    }else{
        if(!"admin".equals(this.login)){
            fc.addMessage("LoginForm:loginID",new    FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Validation Login","Login "+this.login+" inexistant!!"));
        }
        if(!"admin".equals(this.password)){
            fc.addMessage("LoginForm:pwdID",new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Validation Pwd","Vérifier votre mot de passe!!"));
        }
        return "echec";
    }

}
```

}

Finally here is the navigation rules in faces-config.xml

```
     <navigation-rule>
    <display-name>pages/login.xhtml</display-name>
    <from-view-id>/pages/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{LoginBean.authentification()}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/pages/menu.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

I have this in my console after execuring applcation:
janv. 09, 2014 11:00:41 PM com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MessageRenderer encodeEnd
WARNING: 'for' attribute cannot be null
Any one know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a capital 'L' in

```
<from-action>#{LoginBean.authentification()}</from-action>
```

It should be lower-case:

```
<from-action>#{loginBean.authentification()}</from-action>
```

Comment: thx  for replying but it doesn't solve the problem.In fact my managed bean's name is LoginBean with a capital "L".

Comment: Is the `authentification()` actually called? Because if the bean is indeed named LoginBean, then the action in the `<h:commandButton>` is wrong or there is a typo here.